# Calculating VWAP stops when there is NaN for Open/High/Low/Close and fills the rest of the rows with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, stock

Sometimes there will be no trading activity for a period of time for a symbol. The volume for this time-period will be 0 and there will be NaN for High, Low and Close for that time-indexed row.

Using the below to create a 'vwap' column (volume weighted average price), the 'vwap' column calculates vwap reasonably well until it reaches the first NaN. After this, all rows have NaN for vwap:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    
    data = [
        {'Volume': 1000, 'Open': 1, 'High':1.1, 'Low':0.5, 'Close':1.05},
        {'Volume': 1000, 'Open': 2, 'High':2.1, 'Low':0.6, 'Close':2.05},
        {'Volume': 1000, 'Open': 3, 'High':3.1, 'Low':0.7, 'Close':3.05},
        {'Volume': 0, 'Open': None, 'High':None, 'Low':None, 'Close':None},
        {'Volume': 1000, 'Open': 4, 'High':4.1, 'Low':0.8, 'Close':4.05},
        {'Volume': 1000, 'Open': 5, 'High':5.1, 'Low':0.9, 'Close':5.05}
    ]
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    v = df['Volume'].values
    h = df['High'].values
    l = df['Low'].values
    c = df['Close'].values
    
    df['vwap'] = np.cumsum(v*(h+l+c)/3) / np.cumsum(v)
    
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Volume  Open  High  Low  Close      vwap
0    1000   1.0   1.1  0.5   1.05  0.883333
1    1000   2.0   2.1  0.6   2.05  1.233333
2    1000   3.0   3.1  0.7   3.05  1.583333
3       0   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN       NaN
4    1000   4.0   4.1  0.8   4.05       NaN
5    1000   5.0   5.1  0.9   5.05       NaN
```

The final 2 rows have NaN for the 'vwap' column, when I'd very much like them to be calculated, without dropping the 4th row (index 3) as that is actually a time-period (eg, 5 minutes) and I'd like to see it displayed as empty when I generate the chart.

Is there a way to get this to work without interpolating results for all rows where there is no trading activity for each column?

Comment: You need to add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I've added some data as an example to make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.nancumsum` instead.

From the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nancumsum.html):

> Return the cumulative sum of array elements over a given axis treating
> Not a Numbers (NaNs) as zero. The cumulative sum does not change when
> NaNs are encountered and leading NaNs are replaced by zeros.
> ...
> See also
> `numpy.cumsum`
> Cumulative sum across array propagating NaNs.

When nans are propagated, as in `np.cumsum`, any calculation involving a nan results in a nan, and that's why you're getting nans in your output starting at the first row with nans.

Instead, you want to treat nans as zeros, which is what `np.nancumsum` does.

```py
>>> no_nans = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> yes_nans = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5])
>>> np.cumsum(no_nans)
array([ 1,  3,  6, 10, 15])
>>> np.cumsum(yes_nans)
array([ 1.,  3., nan, nan, nan])
>>> np.nancumsum(no_nans)
array([ 1,  3,  6, 10, 15])
>>> np.nancumsum(yes_nans)
array([ 1.,  3.,  3.,  7., 12.])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the explanation. I was worried that treating nans as zero would result in a very distorted vwap line as although it makes sense for volume, the high/low/close prices were not 0 just non-existant - but it seems to have worked well.